# Ant: How to Install a Compiled Program (FOP 1.0)

Tags: java, ant, installation

The version of Ubuntu I use provides FOP 0.95. Its having problems, so I wanted to try the latest version of FOP. I successfully downloaded and built the sources.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to install FOP 1.0. The build instructions (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/compiling.html) did not cover the topic, and the README does not offer any instructions.

I naively tried `ant install --prefix=/usr/local` which failed. Ant listed its flags and switches, but did not include an install option. Next, I performed `sudo cp ./fop /usr/local/bin`, which resulted in the following

```
$fop -V
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fop/cli/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fop.cli.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.fop.cli.Main. Program will exit.
```

How does one install a program with Ant?

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncompress the download to a directory.

Add that directory to your path.

```
export PATH=~/tech/lang/java/fop/fop-1.0/:$PATH
```

That's it:
    Daves-MacBook-Pro:~ Dave$ fop -V

```
USAGE
fop [options] [-fo|-xml] infile [-xsl file] [-awt|-pdf|-mif|-rtf|-tiff|-png|-pcl|-ps|-txt|-at [mime]|-print] <outfile>
 [OPTIONS]  
  -version          print FOP version and exit
  -d                debug mode   
  -x                dump configuration settings  
  # etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. The download directory is my desktop, which does not make a lot of sense. Isn't there a directory structure such as `/usr/bin/`, `usr/share`, etc? Shouldn't `install` handle it (if I could figure out how to run it in Java)?

Comment: You put it there; if it doesn't make sense, that's on you ;) It doesn't matter where you put it. Put it somewhere, then add it to your path. I don't know why you think there's an install.

Comment: Thanks Dave. "You put it there" - I thought I did - but the program was threw an exception about missing classes. Perhaps I should ask: "How does one *fully* compile a Java program so it can be put somewhere"?

Comment: @noloader ... It's compiled. There's nothing to compile. It runs out-of-the-box (assuming you got the -bin download). Decompress. That creates a directory. Put it somewhere. Add it to your classpath. See the above? Did that just now; works fine. Works the same on my Ubuntu box. You copied a file. You can't just copy a file; that's why I said "add that directory to your path".

Comment: Thanks Dave. I think there's a disconnect here (due to me). "Put it somewhere" - I did. After I built it, I put it in /usr/local/bin, which is on path. My apologies.

Comment: Dave - for what its worth, I've been building and installing other's gear for years (close to 20 now) in C and C++. I had Java in college, but did not like the language because it was "build once, debug everywhere". So I dropped it 10 about years ago.

Comment: @noloader If you put the fop *directory* in `/bin`, then you need to add the `fop` directory to your classpath. If you put only the `fop` *shell script* on your path, then it will break, and you need to add the `fop` *directory* to your path. I would not put the `fop` directory in `/bin`, I would put it somewhere reasonable, and have a versioned directory name. You could symlink to that if you want, but I prefer a very granular path, and refer to specific versions.

Comment: OK. I give. Apparently, Java is still screwed up (just like I remembered). Its ridiculous the program does not have an install (apparently its non-trivial) and one must modify paths when there are well known paths such a `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. `rm -rf` will fix this problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @noloader ... It's not really all that screwed up, you're just used to a very specific environment, and won't do something else. You could do a recursive copy of the `fop` directory contents into a `/bin` dir if it's really that important to you, I just wouldn't, when it's pretty trivial to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of **PATH** and environment variables in Java.

The error is being caused because java cannot find the class libraries it requires.

You will find that fop is a script which invokes java with the appropriate parameters for this java application.

You also need to check your java installation and make sure everything is straight.

Comment: "Welcome to the world of path and environment variables is Java." Lol.... So how does one install this stuff?

Comment: Well, generally speaking java is sorta like old DOS programs in as much as there is no real installation.  It the data directories and what not are jake then the command line points everything to the right jar files; however, your base java installation could have issues since it needs its own base libraries it needs.  Google for "validating java install"